# Unity Facebook SDK for ios 9 uses web browser rather than facebook app

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, ios9

After ios 9, my game(powered by Unity3d) required new Unity Facebook SDK. Now i am using Facebook SDK v 7.1.0. However for ios 9 devices, facebook does not use its app, i.e. facebook login is ok but it uses web browser(Safari). I do not get any error, etc. Below ios 9 devices no problem like this appears. I basically followed these instructions https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 . Is there anyone to help/guide me?

Comment: It is by design that the web browser is used.

Comment: So, is facebook app unavailable from ios9 ?

Comment: No. It exists but it will not be used for login

Comment: Also sharing, recommending, etc. it uses web browser(safari). How did you get info claims that it is by design?

Answer (score 0):

It is Facebook's SDK that decides which app to open to log in or share and for iOS 9 it is Safari. You can read more here. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9

Comment: do consider summarizing your findings instead of link only answers

Comment: The question says it launches the browser instead of what the link says "Safari View Controller(SVC)", which is launched inside the app. I have the same problem with unity facebook sdk. But I don't have this problem with Facebook SDK for iOS.